# Silence valgrind param write(buf) points to uninitialised byte(s)

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, valgrind

I've got C code like the following (minimal reproducible example):

```
BYTE *myPointer;
doStuff(&myPointer); //mallocs space and sets myPointer to point to this space


FILE* myFile = fopen(fileName, "rb+");
fseek(myFile, 0, SEEK_SET);

fwrite(myPointer, 32, 1, myFile); //<------- problematic line
```

now this code works and does what it is supposed to, but valgrind throws the following error at the line `fwrite(myPointer, 32, 1, myFile);`:

```
Syscall param write(buf) points to uninitialised byte(s)
```

and I think it's because Valgrind thinks that myPointer is unitialized.

This is fair but inside the doStuff function, I'm mallocing space and setting myPointer to point at it, so everything works as expected.

Is there someway I can let valgrind know this/silence the error?

Thanks

Comment: You must not be doing it correctly, or `valgrind` wouldn't complain that it's uninitialized. Post the code of `doStuff()`.

Comment: It's not enough to allocate the memory, you also have to initialize the contents of the memory. Did you fill in at least 32 bytes?

Comment: ah okay great thanks so much, I think it is something wrong with doStuff(), I'll dig into it some more, didn't realize valgrind wouldn't complain otherwise!

Comment: use calloc and the memory will be initialized

Answer (score 0):

The `fwrite` function is used to *write* data to a file.  This means (in this case) that the `myPointer` is expected to point to 32 bytes of data that will be written to the disk.

This is of course a problem because unless `doStuff` is populating the memory `myPointer` points to then those bytes will in fact be uninitialized.

Assuming you actually want to read from the file, use `fread` instead.

```
fread(myPointer, 32, 1, myFile);
```

If you in fact want to write, make sure that at least 32 bytes that `myPointer` points were in fact set to some value.

Comment: got it thanks so much, I do want to write so I think it's something off with the doStuff() function! Will post my result here when I figure it out :)